# rbenv and passenger - cannot install from not root user account(sudo group)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rbenv

I'm just trying to setup my first rails server - on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed rbenv (as user: `deployer` with groups sudo and admin). Now trying to install passenger according to their docs.

I run `passenger-install-nginx-module` it starts but then I get

```
Please specify a prefix directory [/opt/nginx]: 

--------------------------------------------

Permission problems

This installer must be able to write to the following directory:

/opt/nginx

But it can't do that, because you're running the installer as deployer.
```

Ok, I run `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module` then, and get `sudo: passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found`.

Does it mean I have to install it by loggin as root, installing whole rbenv for root user and then install passenger? Every tutorial I read they run it from not root user account :/, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, as your deployer user run ``which passenger-install-nginx-module`` to get the full path of the passenger script, then ``su``, and run the command with a fullpath. You need this script only one time ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Post it as an answer so I could approve it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you have to run the `passenger-install-nginx-module` as root with the full path, because it is not in the `$PATH` var of your bash. To find out the path, run `which passenger-install-nginx-module`

Comment: In short: `sudo \`which passenger-install-nginx-module\``